# Problema con WebBrowser

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo un problema al intentar abrir una página hecha en *Java* de un dispositivo que está en mi red local.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código:

```
namespace RFIDIsaiv._1
{
    public partial class WebConf : Form
    {
        public WebConf()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void WebConf_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://172.16.2.253:3161/index.html"));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué pasa al darle click en Sí?

Comment: solo me muestra el form, en blanco

Comment: y si agregas el JavaScript? y detalles del navegador que estás usando? bienvenido al sitio, date una vuelta por https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas cómo funciona SOes :D

Comment: A ok Fredyfx, esa pagina la puedo visualizar en chrome, internet explorer y tambien en fire fox, de echo esa pagina es un web admin para acceder a un dispositivo algo parecido a un router.

Comment: los navegadores de microsoft son algo especiales te recomiendo primero que entres a la uri  desde chrome y habilites las herramientas de desarrollo y ve en la pestaña consola y revisa si tienes algún error en el script

Answer (score 0):

Intenta ignorando los errores generados por el `webControl`:

```
webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
```

Puede que con esto, te deje visualizar la página web dentro del control.

Comment: Ya realice la acción que me comentaste, puse el código que me pusiste en el load de mi form, sin embargo solo me quita la pantalla del error y aun no me muestra la pagina web, que podrá ser que no me deje visualizar dicha pagina?

Comment: Ok, eh estado investigando y parece que este control trabaja por defecto con las funcionalidades de IE7 y lo mas seguro es que tu JavaScript no es compatible con este navegador. Voy a indagar un poco mas haber que se puede hacer con este caso.

Comment: @sehonisai, que pena contigo en este momento no puedo verificar algunas soluciones que he encontrado. Básicamente se trata de crear algunas claves en el REGEDIT de Windows. te voy a dejar los vínculos para que los revises. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25142594/allowing-javascript-to-run-on-a-windows-form-web-browser` y este otro  `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922308/use-latest-version-of-internet-explorer-in-the-webbrowser-control`

Comment: Muchas Gracias Weimar por el empeño a mi duda, indagare un poco en los link que me proporcionaste, y reitero mi agradecimiento a tu ayuda proporcionada